# What have become of Ubuntu JeOS? Does it have a successor?

Tags: release-management

A while ago Ubuntu had a variant called "[JeOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_JeOS)"  (**J** ust **e** nough **O** perating **S** ystem). It was a minimal CD image (.iso) that one could use to get a minimal operating system installation, that could be further expanded via `apt-get`.

JeOS was abandoned. What's the closest thing to it today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spiritual successor to JeOS is Ubuntu Core:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core

Comment: Unfortunately for me, unlike [JeOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_JeOS), [Ubuntu Core](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core) doesn't have an installer. If one would need to get a starting point for their own distribution and would need an Ubuntu Core + Installer, how should one go about it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer to that, beyond my means; but I can help get you an answer from someone else, post it as a new question and send me the link.

Comment: I found out there's also an official [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), as well as unofficial [Ubuntu Mini Remix](http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/). Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

FTR: JeOS still exists. 
You can find it at http://www.pqr.com/ubuntu-jeos and http://virtualappliances.eu